# Changing custom text view size using shared preference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, text-size

I want to change the size of the text of my `CustomTextView` using a value stored in `SharedPreferences`.

The code for my `CustomTextView`:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    private SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

And my `SharedPreference` code:

```
public class SharedPreference {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "AOP_PREFS";

    public static final String INT_KEY = "Text Size";

    public SharedPreference() {
        super();
    }

    public void saveInt (Context context, int size) {
        ...
    }

    public int getInt(Context context) {
        ...
    }
}
```